# I get this error: "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given" even when the value is of type array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add a value to the end of an array. I am using:

```
array_push($this->_attributes["class"],$value);
```

Now I know that the first parameter has to be an array. Upon inspection :

```
var_dump($this->_attributes["class"]); die(0);
array_push($this->_attributes["class"],$value);
```

I can see that the value being passed in is indeed an array as it should be. I am not sure how or why I am getting a string being passed. The output of the `var_dump` look like such:

```
array (size=0)
    empty
```

Why or how is `$this->_attributes["class"]` being seen as a string and not an array?

**Edit:**
If I invert the two lines like so:

```
array_push($this->_attributes["class"],$value);
var_dump($this->_attributes["class"]); die(0);
```

The var_dump looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
   0 => string 'btn' (length=3)
```

This is the expected output. If I remove the var_dump, I get a fatal error on the array_push again.

** Full Class Declaration**
This is enough of the class I able building for this example:

```
class Tag
{
    protected $_attributes = array("class"=>array());

    public function setAttribute($attribute,$value)
    {
        if( $attribute === "class" ) {
            $this->setClassAttribute($value);
        }
        $this->_attributes[$attribute] = $value;
    }
    public function setClassAttribute($value)
    {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            foreach ($value as $c) {
                $this->setClassAttribute($c);
            }
            return;
        }
        // var_dump($this->_attributes["class"]); die(0);
        array_push($this->_attributes["class"],$value);
        // var_dump($this->_attributes["class"]); die(0);
    }
}
```

To execute it:

```
$tag = new Tag();
$tag->setAttribute("class","btn");
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal piece of code with which we can reproduce this. Definition of `$this->_attributes`?

Comment: Your updated sample doesn't reproduce the issue. - edit: looks like you have to set twice to cause.

Comment: Try using `$this->_attributes["class"][] = $value` instead. It might work, and if not, then you will likely get a more descriptive error.

Comment: @HPierce I am using xdebug. But this is not the case. If I were to `var_dump($this->_attributes)` then I would get more of a result like you are talking about. I will add it in the question so it is more legible.

Comment: @SeinopSys `$this->_attributes["class"][] = $value` throw a `[] operator not supported for strings`. Which is essentially the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public function setAttribute($attribute,$value)
{
    if( $attribute === "class" ) {
        $this->setClassAttribute($value);
    }
    $this->_attributes[$attribute] = $value;
}
```

setClassAttribute is indeed setting the value to `array("btn")`. Afterwards, it's being overwritten by the line outside the statement. Try:

```
public function setAttribute($attribute,$value)
{
    if( $attribute === "class" ) {
        $this->setClassAttribute($value);
    } else {
        $this->_attributes[$attribute] = $value;
    }
}
```

---

REPL:

```
php > $tag = new Tag();
php > $tag->setAttribute("class","btn");
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "btn"
}
php > $tag->setAttribute("class","btn");
string(3) "btn"

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in php shell code on line 21
string(3) "btn"
```

Comment: After adding the `else` clause, the error goes away. Thank you.